# Sequence contains more than one matching element в FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты

Получаю ошибку Sequence contains more than one matching element в методе FirstOrDefault. Ошибка появляется в проекте с тестами. Версия EF фреймворков одинаковая. Разница только в версии .NET, основной проект .NET 5.0, проект с тестами .NET 6.0, я очень сомниваюсь что проблема в этом.
**Получаю ошибку в тесте:**

> Message:  System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer
> for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an
> exception.
> ---- System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains more than one matching element
>
> Stack Trace:  QueryableMethods.get_Select()
> QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression) MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> QueryTranslationPreprocessor.NormalizeQueryableMethod(Expression
> expression) QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
> QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
> Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
> QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression
> query, IModel model, Boolean async)
> <>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0() CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1
> compiler) QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
> EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
> Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1
> predicate) MainAPIService.ctor(AppDBContext context, String
> serverCode, Boolean SSLIgnore) line 24 Service1C8.ctor(AppDBContext
> context) line 12 Service1C8Tests.CreateRepositoryAsync() line 53
> Service1C8Tests.GetGasInfoAsyncNotNULLResult() line 38
> <>c.b__128_0(Object state)
> ----- Inner Stack Trace ----- ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
> Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
> predicate, Boolean& found) Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) QueryableMethods.cctor()

**Сам тест:**

```
public class Service1C8Tests
{
    private DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> dbContextOptions;
    public Service1C8Tests()
    {
        var dbName = $"AuthorPostsDb_{DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()}";
        dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDBContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName)
            .Options;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void SaveTimeOnPointAsyncNotNULLResult()
    {
        //Arrange
        Service1C8 service = await CreateRepositoryAsync();

        var test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        //Act
        ResponseModel1C result =  await service.SaveTimeOnPointAsync("123456", "10", "in");

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
    [Fact]
    public async void GetGasInfoAsyncNotNULLResult()
    {
        //Arrange
        Service1C8 service = await CreateRepositoryAsync();

        var test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        //Act
        GasResponseModel1C result = await service.GetGasInfoAsync("123456", GasTypeInfo.History);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }

    private async Task<Service1C8> CreateRepositoryAsync()
    {
        AppDBContext context = new AppDBContext(dbContextOptions);
        await PopulateDataAsync(context);
        return new Service1C8(context);
    }

    private async Task PopulateDataAsync(AppDBContext context)
    {
        context.RemoteServers.Add(new RemoteServer
        {
            Code = "Service1C8",
            Host = "some",
            Port = "80",
            SSL = false,
            Login = "testserv",
            Password = "1",
            Token = "dGVzdHasdas==",
            TokenLifeEnd = DateTime.Parse("2023-10-19 13:15:26.2500954"),
            AuthorizationHeader = "Basic"

        });

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**Место где она появляеться:**

```
protected MainAPIService(AppDBContext context, string serverCode, bool SSLIgnore = false)
{
    _context = context;

    _server = _context.RemoteServers 
        .Include(rs => rs.ServiceProxy)
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == serverCode); //Вот тут выстреливает ексепшен, который я привел выше.

    if(_server == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Remote server {serverCode} is NULL! Check DB table!");
    }
    else
    {
        WebProxy proxy = null;

        if (_server.UseProxy)
        {
            proxy = new WebProxy()
            {
                Address = (new UriBuilder(
                    _server.ServiceProxy.ProxySSL ? "https" : "http",
                    _server.ServiceProxy.ProxyHost,
                    _server.ServiceProxy.ProxyPort)).Uri,
                UseDefaultCredentials = _server.ServiceProxy.UseDefaultCredentials,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = _server.ServiceProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal,
            };

            if(!_server.ServiceProxy.UseDefaultCredentials)
            {
                proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                    userName: _server.ServiceProxy.Login,
                    password: _server.ServiceProxy.Password
                );
            }
        }

        _httpHelper = new HTTPHelper(
            _server.Host,
            _server.Port,
            _server.SSL,
            SSLIgnore,
            proxy
        );

        TokenAlive = DateTime.Now < _server.TokenLifeEnd;

        if(TokenAlive)
        {
            _httpHelper.SetAuthToken(_server.Token, _server.AuthorizationHeader);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**
EF версия в обоих проектах:5.0.3

**AppDbContext**:

```
public class AppDBContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RemoteServer> RemoteServers { get; set; }

    public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RemoteServer>().HasData(
            new RemoteServer[]
            {
                new RemoteServer { Id = 1, Code="RemoteIntegrationServer", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=false, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 2, Code="SignServer", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=false, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 3, Code="FireBaseProxy", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=false, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 4, Code="AlarmServer", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=false, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 5, Code="PortalUZDServer", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=true, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 6, Code="Service1C8", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=false, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Basic", UseProxy = false},
                new RemoteServer { Id = 7, Code="VodafoneService", Host="", Port="", Login="", Password = "", Name="", SSL=true, Token="", AuthorizationHeader="Bearer", UseProxy = false},
            }
        );

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Global Query Filters нет, Interceptors тоже нет.

Comment: Странно. Такую ошибку может выдавать метод `Single[OrDefault]`. А `First[OrDefault]` не должен.

Comment: Укажите версию EF. Покажите `AppDBContext` и код сущностей (только то, что задействовано в данном тесте). Есть ли Global Query Filters? Используются ли Interceptors? И т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, я знаю. Ошибка кстати не меняется, даже если я там сделаю просто ToList без параметров, все равно будет ругаться на Sequence contains more than one matching element. Не могу понять где проблема, как будто под капотом имитации контекста базы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov дополнил вопрос

Comment: InMemory категорически не рекомендуется для юнит-тестов. Может дело в этом. Больше у меня предположений пока нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я бы принял в качестве ответа альтернативу inMemory, как бы вы поступили в данном кейсе.